# Problema con el CORS en Springboot

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, cors, spring-security

Estoy haciendo un proyecto full stack con Angular y Springboot.
Mi problema surge cuando quiero realizar el cierre de sesion del usuario que esta logeado pero me tira el siguente error :

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/api/v1/auth/logout'
> from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy:
> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource.
>
> GET http://localhost:8080/api/v1/auth/logout net::ERR_FAILED 200 (OK)

**BACKEND:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration{

    private final JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthFilter;
    private final AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;
    private final LogoutHandler logoutHandler;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .authorizeHttpRequests(req ->
                        req.requestMatchers("**")
                                .permitAll()
                                .requestMatchers("/api/v1/management/**").hasAnyRole(ADMIN.name(), MANAGER.name())
                                .requestMatchers(GET, "/api/v1/management/**").hasAnyAuthority(ADMIN_READ.name(), MANAGER_READ.name())
                                .requestMatchers(POST, "/api/v1/management/**").hasAnyAuthority(ADMIN_CREATE.name(), MANAGER_CREATE.name())
                                .requestMatchers(PUT, "/api/v1/management/**").hasAnyAuthority(ADMIN_UPDATE.name(), MANAGER_UPDATE.name())
                                .requestMatchers(DELETE, "/api/v1/management/**").hasAnyAuthority(ADMIN_DELETE.name(), MANAGER_DELETE.name())
                                .anyRequest()
                                .authenticated()
                )
                .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(STATELESS))
                .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
                .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .logout(logout ->
                        logout.logoutUrl("/api/v1/auth/logout")
                                .addLogoutHandler(logoutHandler)
                                .logoutSuccessHandler((request, response, authentication) -> SecurityContextHolder.clearContext())


                )
        ;

        return http.build();
    }



}
```

Vi en internet que recomendaban usar esto pero no se como usarlo del todo

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class CorsConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
                .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE")
                .allowedHeaders("Origin", "Content-Type", "Accept")
                .allowCredentials(true);
    }
}
```

Este es un servicio que tengo para logout

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class LogOutService  implements LogoutHandler {

    private final TokenRepository tokenRepository;

    @Override
    public void logout(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) {
        final String authHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        final String jwt;
        if (authHeader == null ||!authHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            return;
        }
        jwt = authHeader.substring(7);
        var storedToken = tokenRepository.findByToken(jwt)
                .orElse(null);
        if (storedToken != null) {
            storedToken.setExpired(true);
            storedToken.setRevoked(true);
            tokenRepository.save(storedToken);
            SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
        }
    }

}
```

**FRONTEND:**

El servicio que utilizo en mi servicio de seguridad

```
public logout(): Observable<any> {
    return this.httpClient.get(this.authURL + 'logout');
  }
```

Este es el procedimiento que utilizo en mi TS.

```
cerrarSesion(): void {
          this.authService.logout().subscribe(
            response => {
              this.toastr.success('Sesión cerrada exitosamente', 'Éxito');
              this.router.navigate(["/"]);
            },
            error => {
              if (error.status === 401) {
                this.toastr.warning('No se pudo cerrar sesión. Sesión ya cerrada o no autorizada.', 'Advertencia');
              } else {
                this.toastr.error('Ha ocurrido un error al cerrar sesión', 'Error');
              }
            }
          );
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

Al final es un proyecto back y otro front, debido a tu configuracion y que yo not engo logout no te puedo ayudar mucho pero tengo este proyecto securizado para ver si te da una idea
https://github.com/carlos033/w2m

Comment: Esto no proporciona una respuesta a la pregunta. Para criticar o pedir aclaración a un autor, deja un comentario debajo de su publicación. - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/404775)

Comment: Si bien este enlace puede responder a la pregunta, es mejor incluir las partes esenciales de la respuesta aquí y proporcionar el enlace como referencia.  Las respuestas que son únicamente un enlace pueden dejar de ser válidas si la página vinculada cambia. - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/404775)